# PHP simpleXML trying to process fairly complex file

Tags: php, xml, parsing, crystal-reports, simplexml

The file I have to work with has the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<FormattedReport xmlns = 'urn:crystal-reports:schemas' xmlns:xsi = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance'>
    <FormattedAreaPair Level="0" Type="Report">
    <FormattedAreaPair Level="1" Type="Details">
    <FormattedArea Type="Details">
        <FormattedSections>
        <FormattedSection SectionNumber="0">
        <FormattedReportObjects>
        FormattedReportObject xsi:type="CTFormattedField" Type="xsd:long" FieldName="{tblCon.ManifestNR}"><ObjectName>ManifestNR1</ObjectName>
        <FormattedValue>1,907</FormattedValue>
        <Value>1907.00</Value>
        </FormattedReportObject>
        <FormattedReportObject xsi:type="CTFormattedField" Type="xsd:timeInstant" FieldName="{tblCon.ShippingDate}"><ObjectName>ShippingDate1</ObjectName>
        <FormattedValue>14/04/2011</FormattedValue>
        <Value>2011-04-14T00:00:00</Value>
        </FormattedReportObject>
        ... so on and so forth ...
        </FormattedReportObjects>
        </FormattedSection>
        </FormattedSections>
        </FormattedArea>
        </FormattedAreaPair>
    <FormattedReportObjects>
        FormattedReportObject xsi:type="CTFormattedField" Type="xsd:long" FieldName="{tblCon.ManifestNR}"><ObjectName>ManifestNR1</ObjectName>
        <FormattedValue>1,907</FormattedValue>
        <Value>1907.00</Value>
        </FormattedReportObject>
        <FormattedReportObject xsi:type="CTFormattedField" Type="xsd:timeInstant" FieldName="{tblCon.ShippingDate}"><ObjectName>ShippingDate1</ObjectName>
        <FormattedValue>14/04/2011</FormattedValue>
        <Value>2011-04-14T00:00:00</Value>
        </FormattedReportObject>
        ... so on and so forth ...
        </FormattedReportObjects>
        </FormattedSection>
        </FormattedSections>
        </FormattedArea>
        </FormattedAreaPair>
 <FormattedAreaPair Level="1" Type="Details">
    <FormattedArea Type="Details">
        <FormattedSections>
        <FormattedSection SectionNumber="0">
        <FormattedReportObjects>
        FormattedReportObject xsi:type="CTFormattedField" Type="xsd:long" FieldName="{tblCon.ManifestNR}"><ObjectName>ManifestNR1</ObjectName>
        <FormattedValue>1,907</FormattedValue>
        <Value>1907.00</Value>
        </FormattedReportObject>
        <FormattedReportObject xsi:type="CTFormattedField" Type="xsd:timeInstant" FieldName="{tblCon.ShippingDate}"><ObjectName>ShippingDate1</ObjectName>
        <FormattedValue>14/04/2011</FormattedValue>
        <Value>2011-04-14T00:00:00</Value>
        </FormattedReportObject>
        ... so on and so forth ...
        </FormattedReportObjects>
        </FormattedSection>
        </FormattedSections>
        </FormattedArea>
        </FormattedAreaPair>
    <FormattedReportObjects>
        FormattedReportObject xsi:type="CTFormattedField" Type="xsd:long" FieldName="{tblCon.ManifestNR}"><ObjectName>ManifestNR1</ObjectName>
        <FormattedValue>1,907</FormattedValue>
        <Value>1907.00</Value>
        </FormattedReportObject>
        <FormattedReportObject xsi:type="CTFormattedField" Type="xsd:timeInstant" FieldName="{tblCon.ShippingDate}"><ObjectName>ShippingDate1</ObjectName>
        <FormattedValue>14/04/2011</FormattedValue>
        <Value>2011-04-14T00:00:00</Value>
        </FormattedReportObject>
        ... so on and so forth ...
        </FormattedReportObjects>
        </FormattedSection>
        </FormattedSections>
        </FormattedArea>
        </FormattedAreaPair>
        </FormattedAreaPair>
        </FormattedReport>
```

So what I'm trying to do, is call a PHP function which will parse the XML and eventually store it in an SQL DB.

for example:

ManifestNR: 1903
ShippingDate: 12/04/2011
CarrierID: TNT03
TrackingRef: 234234232
... etc for each record ...

so i've set about trying to do this using DOM and then stumbled across simpleXML, I've read several tuts, and searched implementations here but I just can't seem to access the data in the final nodes (or any other data tbh). Is simpleXML a no-no with these kind of structures?

The latest PHP I'm using is:

```
<?php

if (file_exists('tracking.xml')) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('tracking.xml');

  //  print_r($xml);

   foreach( $xml as $FormattedReport->FormattedAreaPair->FormattedAreaPair ) 
        {
        foreach($FormattedReport as $node->FormattedArea->FormattedSections->FormattedSection->FormattedReportObjects)
        echo $node->FormattedReportObject->Value;
        }

} else {
    exit('Failed to open xml');
}
?>
```

I've tried to strip it right back to basics, but still no luck. Doesn't echo a result.

Thanks for your time guys!

**SOLVED**

Anyone in similar circumstances heres a bit of direction.

1. ignore the root node, thats your default $variable when you import the XML string/file
2. If you have nested groups create a node to the parent first like so  $xml->FormattedAreaPair->FormattedAreaPair as $parentnode
3. Using your parent node loop through all the children
4. If you have an attribute field access it as follows: (string) $node['FieldName'])
5. Compare the retrieved attribute with a string and then handle the result.
6. Stop pulling your hair out.

   `//print_r($xml); 
   foreach( $xml->FormattedAreaPair->FormattedAreaPair as $parentnode ) { 
       foreach($parentnode->FormattedArea->FormattedSections->FormattedSection->FormattedReportObjects->FormattedReportObject as $node){ 
           //echo "FormattedValue: ".$node->FormattedValue."<br />"; 
           switch((string) $node['FieldName']){ 
               case '{tblCon.ManifestNR}': 
                   echo 'Manifest: '.$node->FormattedValue."<br />"; 
                   break; 
               case '{tblCon.ShippingDate}': 
                   echo 'Shipping Date: '.$node->FormattedValue."<br />"; 
                   break; 
               case '{tblCon.CarrierID}': 
                   echo 'Carrier ID: '.$node->FormattedValue."<br />"; 
                   break; 
               case '{tblCon.CustConRefTX}': 
                   echo 'Customer Reference: '.$node->FormattedValue."<br />"; 
                   break; 
               case '{tblCon.ServiceCodeTX}': 
                   echo 'Service Code: '.$node->FormattedValue."<br />"; 
                   break; 
               case '{tblCon.TotalWeightNR}': 
                   echo 'Total Weight: '.$node->FormattedValue."<br />"; 
                   break; 
               case '{tblCon.ValueNR}': 
                   echo 'Value: '.$node->FormattedValue."<br />"; 
                   break; 
               case '{tblCon.TotalVolumeNR}': 
                   echo 'Total Volume: '.$node->FormattedValue."<br />"; 
                   break; 
               case '{tblCon.GoodsDesc}': 
                   echo 'Goods Description: '.$node->FormattedValue."<br />"; 
                   break; 
               case '{tblConAddr.ReceiverNameTX}': 
                   echo 'Receiver Name: '.$node->FormattedValue."<br />"; 
                   break; 
               case '{@SalesOrder}': 
                   echo 'Sales Order: '.$node->FormattedValue."<br />"; 
                   break; 
               case '{@TrackingReference}': 
                   echo 'Tracking Reference: '.$node->FormattedValue."<br />"; 
                   break;
           }
       }
   echo "---------------------------- <br />";
   }`


   } 
   else { 
       exit('Failed to open xml'); 
   }

   ?>

Comment: getting somewhere now, had a little tinker.

`<?php

if (file_exists('tracking.xml')) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('tracking.xml');
 
    //print_r($xml);

   foreach( $xml->FormattedAreaPair->FormattedAreaPair->FormattedArea->FormattedSections->FormattedSection->FormattedReportObjects->FormattedReportObject as $node ) 
        {
  echo $node->Value;
  }
  
} else {
    exit('Failed to open xml');
}
?>`

Comment: latest code loops through it and grabs its all if anyone wants it :)

`<?php

if (file_exists('tracking.xml')) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('tracking.xml');
 
    //print_r($xml);

   foreach( $xml->FormattedAreaPair->FormattedAreaPair as $parentnode ) 
        {
  foreach($parentnode->FormattedArea->FormattedSections->FormattedSection->FormattedReportObjects->FormattedReportObject as $node){
  echo "FormattedValue: ".$node->FormattedValue."<br />";
  }
  }
  
} else {
    exit('Failed to open xml');
}
?>`

Comment: if anyone has any better suggestions on accessing the nodes via the name, rather than drilling down to one specific tag, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [examples in the Manual](http://de.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) should suffice (Example #4 in particular). You seem like a sufficiently clever fellow. The problem is that *you're doing it wrong*.

**example.php**

```
<?php
$xmlstr = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?>
<movies>
 <movie>
  <title>PHP: Behind the Parser</title>
  <characters>
   <character>
    <name>Ms. Coder</name>
    <actor>Onlivia Actora</actor>
   </character>
   <character>
    <name>Mr. Coder</name>
    <actor>El Act&#211;r</actor>
   </character>
  </characters>
  <plot>
   So, this language. It's like, a programming language. Or is it a
   scripting language? All is revealed in this thrilling horror spoof
   of a documentary.
  </plot>
  <great-lines>
   <line>PHP solves all my web problems</line>
  </great-lines>
  <rating type="thumbs">7</rating>
  <rating type="stars">5</rating>
 </movie>
</movies>
XML;
?>
```

**Example #4**

```
<?php
include 'example.php';

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);

/* For each <character> node, we echo a separate <name>. */
foreach ($xml->movie->characters->character as $character) {
   echo $character->name, ' played by ', $character->actor, PHP_EOL;
}

?>
```

Notice that when using the `foreach` construct you need to specify the path to the nodes of a certain type. The second item in the `foreach` is just an (empty) variable that you use to store the current node in the iteration.

Comment: this is not an answer. He knows he's doing it wrong, that's why he's asking

Comment: Of course it's an answer. It provides a link to a tutorial, which, if read, will help him solve his problem. Not all answers need to be direct. I'll copy paste the code in Example #4 if that makes you fell better, but I didn't think it was necessary.

Comment: thanks Alin, I had a look through it and it gave me a few ideas. Problem is with my XML syntax you can see it defines strange attributes and objects, which I'm struggling to try and access. I can now iterate through the XML and pull out all the information by a defined value (FormattedValue). I think I might be able to handle the information this way, and store the results in an object and sort it there.

Comment: @tutts From what I see only attributes make use of namespaces. Check out this method http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php if you want to get the attributes for a specific namespace. Also if the answer helped you I would appreciate a +1 to offset the uncalled for (!) downvote from @pleasedontbelong .

Comment: Hi thanks again Alin, although I've just figured it out (found the attributes doc)! I will post my solution now. I would up vote you, although I don't have enough rep :( sorry.

Comment: it wasn't uncalled for.. "read the doc, you're doing it wrong" it's not an answer, I could say the same for 99% of the questions here, you could even answer that without having even read the question. But i'll remove the downvote for the explanation on namespaces

Comment: @pleasedontbelong It seems we have different standards. I consider *read the docs + the link to the actual portion to read* useful in general. Anyway, there's no point in continuing this polemic. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

How to access attributes like i:nil with simplexml ( XMLSchema-instance ) :

Xml :

```
<item i:nil="true"/>
```

Php :

```
(bool) $item->attributes('i',true)->nil;
```

Answer (score 0):

The file I was dealing with was ~1GB so I couldn't load the xml file all at once.
Here's the CI controller I made to parse the Crystal Reports XML.

```
<?php

class Parse_crystal_reports_xml extends CI_Controller {

    function index(){
        $base_path = "/path/to/xml/";
        $xml_file = "xml_file.xml";
        $file_header = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>';
        $separator = '<FormattedAreaPair Level="1" Type="Details">';
        $xml_data = explode($separator, str_replace($file_header, '', file_get_contents($base_path.$xml_file)));
        $bad_names = array('xsi:','xsd:');
        foreach($xml_data as $block_num => $block) : 
            if(!$block_num) : continue; endif;
            $fields = new SimpleXMLElement(str_replace($bad_names, '', $file_header."\n".$separator.$block));
            $temp_array = array();
            foreach($fields->FormattedArea->FormattedSections->FormattedSection->FormattedReportObjects->FormattedReportObject as $field_num => $field) :
                // print_r($field);
                $temp_array[$this->make_slug($field['FieldName'])] = $this->clean_word((string)$field->FormattedValue);
            endforeach;
            // print_r($fields);
            print_r($temp_array);
            die;
        endforeach;
    }

    function make_slug($string){
        return strtolower(trim(preg_replace('/\W+/', '_', $string), '_'));
    }

    function clean_word($string){
        return trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $string));
    }
}
?>
```